# How to make object file with different command and .exe with different command in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I like to know how to generate object file with different g++ command ex:

- g++ -pipe -D__GNUWIN32__ -c main.cpp -o main.o

And using that main.o file need to generate .exe file with different command ex

- g++ -mwindows main.o -o main.exe
  How to do it ...

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, especially since CMake is meant to make build configurations *independent* of the actual compiler... -- What is it that you are *actually trying to achieve*?

Comment: But it is easy on makefile to geberate such command but in cmake it always make executable file with the same command used to make object file

Comment: CMake is not make. Probably you should read more about the background of CMake.

Comment: There are a dozen ways to set what options CMake uses exactly to generate object files / binaries. But you do not want to "use exactly these options", you have an abstract goal. I can't tell what that is, because `-pipe` and `-mwindows` don't look like valid options to me, and I don't know what `__GNUWIN32__` should be for. If you're looking for e.g. a MinGW build, the approach would not be fiddling with compiler options, but using a toolchain file -- i.e. I could tell you how to set specific compiler options all day, but we'd be ignoring easier solutions. **What is your actual problem?**

Comment: Looks like you search the way how to pass flags to compiler and to the linker. Flags for c++ compiler corresponds to CMake variable [CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html), flags for linker corresponds to [CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS.html) one.

Comment: My actual problem is to use wxWidgets with Cmake problem is none provide a actual solution i know how to compile it but How to change compiler on CMake to produce object file and then .exe file

Comment: In you example you use **same** compiler(`g++`), but with *different arguments*. Or you want to use different commands? In that case, please, provide more concrete example.

Comment: Ok I give example to use wxWidgets in widows you have to compile the file

Comment: So here is command   g++ -pipe -mthread -I C:/wxWidgets-3.0.0/include -I C:/wxWidgets-3.0.0/lib/gcc_dll/mswu -g -Wall -c xxx.cpp -o test.o

Comment: To make executable file g++ -LC:/wxWidgets-3.0.0/lib/gcc_dll test.o -o test.exe -mwindows -lwxmsw30u

Comment: So `-pipe -mthread -I C:/wxWidgets-3.0.0/include -I C:/wxWidgets-3.0.0/lib/gcc_dll/mswu -g -Wall` are *compiler flags*, ` -LC:/wxWidgets-3.0.0/lib/gcc_dll` are *linker flags*, as I said before. `-mwindows -lwxmsw30u` are libraries to link with.

Answer (score 0):

You should try **object library** target and **set_target_properties** command.

The [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) enables to create a target and to compile object files without linking.

The [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) command enables, among others, to add specific flags to a target.

Here's a small example using your question :

```
add_library(main_object OBJECT main.cpp)
set_target_properties(main_object PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-pipe -D__GNUWIN32__")
add_executable(main $<TARGET_OBJECTS:main_object>)
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-mwindows")
```